# Salesforce lightning custom label not getting updated even after page load

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I am having issue with Custom label behavior. I have created Custom Label to Show/Hide Custom Related list. This custom label is set to **false** for the first time. It is made **true** to test but still **$Label.c.Switch** gives false. I tried to clear cache, tried to reload the page many times and also tried with Private window mode. Sometimes It will be true and sometimes false.

Below is the code using Custom Label

```
    <aura:if isTrue="{! $Label.c.Switch == 'true'}">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.failedToLoadDynamicComponent}">
            <h3>Failed to dynamically load Safety Letters related list.</h3>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                {!v.body}
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>        
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <h3>Please make Switch to true to see records</h3>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
```

Is anyone else facing this issue or has found a solution for it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> key + <kbd>F5</kbd> Function, then it is working as accepted